# Sending JSON data to database with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am learning JSON with PHP and I run into an problem

I am trying to insert my sizes merged string to database products table under sizes column
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYgGy.jpg)

---

This Is what I tried:

I have a function that is called **saveChangesSizes** where 
I have tried used JSON.stringify() to convert a JavaScript object into a string

```
$("#saveChangesSizes").click(function(){
    console.log("1");
    var velicine="";
    var niz=new Array();
    for(var i=1; i<=12;i++){
        if($("#size_" + i).val()!=""){
            niz.push({size: $("#size_" + i).val(), qty: $("#qty_" + i).val()});
            velicine+=$("#size_" + i).val() + ":" + $("#qty_" + i).val() + ",";
        }
    }
    console.log(niz);
    if(velicine.length>0){
        velicine=velicine.substring(0,velicine.length-1);
    }
    $("#qtyandsizes").val(JSON.stringify(niz));
    $("#sizes").val(velicine);
     $("#sizesModal").foundation("close");
     return false;
});
```

---

After I submit my sizes from modal they are stored in [sizes and quantity preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvspz.jpg) label with correct formating, that is string.

My preview label have an id of "sizes" and value of "$sizes"

With **PHP** 
 I have defined $sizes in if post condition

```
 if($_POST){
 $sizes = ((isset($_POST['qtyandsizes']) && $_POST['qtyandsizes'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['qtyandsizes']):'');
```

I have query for **insert** to my database :

```
$insertSql=$veza->prepare("INSERT INTO products (`sizes`) VALUES ('$sizes');");
 $insertSql->execute();
```

What I am getting into my database is JSON object like so :

> [{"size":"medium","qty":"2"},{"size":"large","qty":"3"}]

---

***Update***

I should somehow return the value of "velicine" to a php variable since it shows the expected format and result with `console.log(velicine)`

I tried replacing `$_POST['qtyandsizes']` to `$_POST['sizes']` but it overwrites anything I manually insert into database size column with empty result

**To provide with more information , this is my full code structure:**

---

PHP open and **PDO** database configuration file included

```
<?php
include_once "../config.php";
```

---

```
 if(isset($_GET['add']) || isset($_GET['edit'])){
   $sizes = ((isset($_POST['sizes']) && $_POST['sizes'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['sizes']):'');

 if(isset($_GET['edit'])){
   $sizes = ((isset($_POST['sizes']) && $_POST['sizes'] != '')?sanitize($_POST['sizes']):$product['sizes']);

 if($_POST)

   $sizes = ((isset($_POST['sizes']) && $_POST['sizes'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['sizes']):'');
```

---

After that comes my query for inserting into the database that I posted above.And where I close my PHP tags.

---

> Opening FORM tags and content bellow :

```
<form action ="sizes.php?<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'edit='.$edit_id:'add=1');?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div class="small-6 large-4 columns ">
   <label>Quantity & Sizes*: </label>
   <button class="button" id="ctl">Quantity & Sizes</button>
</div>
//Id = ctl is used to open my modal where I am inputting sizes

<div class="small-6 large-4 columns ">
  <label for ="sizes">Sizes & Qty Preview</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="size" id="sizes" value="<?php echo $sizes;?>"readonly> 
</div>
```

---

**Notice** `$sizes` variable, that is being echoed in correct format to Sizes and Quantaty preview label is what I want to insert into the database, but for some reason it doesn't work.

---

And my submit button and where my Form ends :

```
 <input type="submit" value="<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'Edit':'Add');?> Product" class="button">


<input type="hidden" name="qtyandsizes" id="qtyandsizes" />

</form>
```

After this comes my foundation reveal modal for adding sizes with button id saveChangesSizes that outputs the result into preview label.

```
 <button class="button"  id="saveChangesSizes"> Save Changes
```

At the end is where javascript saveChangesSizes function is.

Comment: What do you expect your database example to look like?

Comment: See the expected result link. It is expected to be merged as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

```
function getSizes($json){

  $json = urldecode($json);

  $array = json_decode($json, true);

  foreach($array as $key){

  $sizes .= $key['size'] . ':' . $key['qty'] . ',';

  }

  $sizes = rtrim($sizes,',');

  return htmlentities($sizes, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

}

echo getSizes($_POST['qtyandsizes']);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168698/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-j-sending-json-data-to-database-with-php).

Comment: Well linter is giving me php error, acctualy it refers me to open dev tools on atom where I Can see this error inside body: platform linux is bluuried

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables in `JS`:

```
1. `niz` which is an `Array`
This `Array` is created in `key value` pair as
size: medium, qty: 2

2. `velicine` which is a `String`
This is created as a concatenated string
medium:2
```

`niz` Array is then converted to `JSON` string and is inserted into `products`  table. `velicine` is just used to display in a `textbox` to the user.

> [{"size":"medium","qty":"2"},{"size":"large","qty":"3"}]

This is a valid JSON string. If you do not want JSON to be stored, replace it with `velicine` at the time of `insert`.

Hope this helps!

**Update 1**

As per your comment, you want to insert `velicine` into the database.

To do so, change following snippet

```
if($_POST){
    $sizes = ((isset($_POST['qtyandsizes']) && $_POST['qtyandsizes'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['qtyandsizes']):'');
```

to

```
if($_POST){
    $sizes = ((isset($_POST['sizes']) && $_POST['sizes'] !='')?sanitize($_POST['sizes']):'');
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I can't find the solution on how to get my javascript value of "velicine" into post and replace it with current insert, where now I have variable $sizes

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't output anything to database, I have tried this before I posted my question